# Как вывести лишь один элемент из списка в модели один ко многим?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Вот как выглядит контроллер:

```
public ActionResult CategoryImage(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    CategoryGallery gallery = mc.CategoriesGallery.Include(g => g.ImagesGallery)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);

    if (gallery == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return PartialView(gallery);
}
```

`src="image.ImageUrl.ToString()"` возвращает множество картинок, работает и без `ToString()`

`src="image.ImageUrl.FirstOrDefault()"` возвращает пустую строку...
`FirstOrDefault(i => i.CategoryGalleryId == Model.Id)` - подобный вариант тоже пустоту...

Пробывал различные вариации, но пока нужного результата не получил... Вообще такое возможно при текущей модели данных?

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос. *src="image.ImageUrl.ToString()" возвращает множество картинок* - заставляет задуматься о том, как это? Что  у Вас и где именно не получается?

Comment: У вас есть сущностью `CategoriesGallery` у которой есть множество `ImagesGallery`, и вы хотите выбрать одну категорию и одну картинку для нее?

Comment: нельзя написать `Include(g => g.ImagesGallery.FirstOrDefault() )` ?

Comment: Include(g => g.ImagesGallery.FirstOrDefault() ) данную комбинацию тоже пробывал использовать ))

Comment: teran вы правильно меня поняли, нужно выбрать одну категорию и из данной категории вывести лишь одну куртинку.

Comment: и чего на выходе то получили? В отладчике после выполнения запроса. а не во вьюшке

Answer (score 0):

```
    var gallery = mc.CategoriesGallery
                      .Include(g => g.ImagesGallery)
                      .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id)
                      .Select(a => new
                          {
                              CategoriesGallery = a,
                              ImagesGallery= a.ImagesGallery.OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
                          });
```